# does HTC Magic Support OpenGl ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have HTC magic (rooted and flashed to android 2.3.4-ginger yoshi1.5).
As it is stated in android documents that android 2.2 supports opengl es 2.0,I want to make a app using opengl es 2.0. 
But ConfigurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion returns 0x10001 ie. opengl es 1.1.
so i want to know does support of opengl es 2.0 for a device depends on hardware or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't support openGL ES 2.0. My previous phone was a rooted HTC Magic too and I was looking if it's able to support oGL ES 2.0. The the documentation says, that Android 2.2  **supports** it, but this doesn't mean that every device running 2.2 is capable to support it. I'm not completely sure, but I think that it's hardware and/or driver related.

Hope it helps

**Edit:**
Bottom of the page under the Hardware support!
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/APIs,_Libraries_and_acronyms

Comment: i had gone through net and didn't find a single site stating that the opengl es 2.0 depends on Gpu driver or hardware. Can u plz provide links which states that. Sorry, i don't have enough reputation to vote u.

Comment: Edited the answer! You don't have to vote up the answer put mark it as checked/answered.