# Google Maps support for OpenGL ES 1.0x Android Devices

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es

I am developing in Android using Gingerbread 2.3.3 (API level 10).

I am concerned about OpenGL support. [The current Google Maps Android API v2 requires OpenGL 2.0](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#requiring_opengl_es_version_2), and it appears that the original Droids (and other "old" devices) do not natively support OpenGL 2.0. [Although hacks exist to add OpenGL 2.0 to the original Droid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=620598). Maps are a fundamental mobile function/service, and I don’t like working with [deprecated code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/).

Besides using the [Static Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), how can I support older OpenGL ES 1.0x Android devices with map functionality? [What is the best way to support both google map apis (v1 and v2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13998911/363829), touches on this but I need to support OpenGL ES 1.0X devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this solution is possible for you but I've just updated our app having both Maps v1 and v2 integrated into it in parallel.

I was able to hide all our mapping functionality behind an interface and have two implementation - one for V1 and one for V2. I'll instantiate the appropriate class based on wether the user has the new maps or don't.

My activities has to extend MapActivity as before and you have to use a standalone MapView instead of MapFragment (and delegate to it the lifecycle calls).

It is more work but if you want to go for safety it is possible.